# Converting Passlib hash salt and digest to regular / PHC Base64

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, passlib

I need to port a passlib (pbkdf2-sha512 to be specific) digest to another system (Auth0) and need to convert it [to PHC string format](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-string-format/blob/master/phc-sf-spec.md) using a B64 encoded salt (regular base64 without padding characters).

Passlib encodes to a shortened base64 format using it's own ['adapted base64 encoding'](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.utils.binary.html#passlib.utils.binary.ab64_encode) method. I basically need to convert that to the B64 format to include in my import file for Auth0.

The [pbkdf2-sha512 documentation](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.pbkdf2_digest.html#passlib.hash.pbkdf2_sha512) explains the output format as:

$pbkdf2-digest$rounds$salt$checksum

My complete pbkdf2-sha512 hash of my password 'Password!' looks like this:

```
$pbkdf2-sha512$25000$8d7bW2stZaw1BoBQyhkjZA$Dszct0GGjjfikK3cJhx.4M.YdOoytY9T5qaib9y8C/gvC1rE4iCWT970bN/MJD81RVToY.855KWRsGoPudA0HA
```

A simple script to output the passlib hash:

```
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha512
print(pbkdf2_sha512.hash("Password!"))
```

From the Passlib documentation, I assume the following:

```
Key size: 16k (128 bits) - this is the default (not specified anywhere in the output) 
Digest type: pbkdf2-sha512 
Rounds: 25000  
Salt: 8d7bW2stZaw1BoBQyhkjZA
Digest / Hash data: Dszct0GGjjfikK3cJhx.4M.YdOoytY9T5qaib9y8C/gvC1rE4iCWT970bN/MJD81RVToY.855KWRsGoPudA0HA
```

What I'm struggling to do is convert the salt and digest to the B64 format required by Auth0. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I've figured it out...
My understanding is that passlib's format simply replaces + with . and strips the padding and white space, so for my needs (vanilla B64 without whitespace or padding), I merely need to replace . with + and I have the correct format.

In my testing I also noticed that key length is 512 bytes (64k) not 128/16 as I originally thought.

I confirmed it using this tool:  https://8gwifi.org/pbkdf.jsp
(Note that padding is added to the salt to make it 24 characters long)

For anyone wanting a bit of background on the Passlib base 64 flavor, see [this post on Google groups](https://groups.google.com/g/passlib-users/c/J-XnaFXprKQ?pli=1).